# How to pass variable to dialog in jQuery

Tags: jquery, user-interface

When clicking this:

```
$('.hor_edit').live('click', function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var name = $(this).attr('name');
                    $('#dialog-form-horario').dialog('open');
                });
```

I want to check the variable when clicking another button inside the dialog:

```
$('#dialog-form-horario').dialog({
            resizable: false,
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {

                'Agregar': function() {
                                    alert(name);
                }
            },

            close: function() {
            }
        });
```

I've read the documentation but seems not clear to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
var name = $(this).attr('name');
$('#dialog-form-horario').data('name', name);
$('#dialog-form-horario').dialog('open');
```

and

```
'Agregar': function() {
    alert($(this).data('name'));
}
```

Comment: Sorry, it works now, I think I need to sleep, I forgot to add the new alert. :-)